# Link to specific tab in wordpress layout?

Tags: wordpress

I have created a layout in Wordpress with a plug-in called builder. I then have a page that uses this layout. The layout contains a area with tabs.

When the user clicks on a link in my main menu he is taken to this page with the first tab open. Can I change the link to take him to the second tab instead?

Actually the menu looks like this

About us
-Overview
-History
-Contact

If the user clicks on about us or overview I want him to go to the first tab.

Comment: bit confused, can you show us an example?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you must create something with an HTML anchor OR

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#tabs #2nditemid').click();
});
```

OR

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tabs li').hide();
 $('#tabs li.2nditemid').show();
    });
```

This may vary a bit but may lead you somewhere

this must be specific only to where you have the tabs... so best is to create a page theme only for this specific page to avoid extra jquery in all pages